# .xinitrc vs. AwesomeWM Autorun programs. Which one's better?

Tags: linux, boot, xorg, window-manager, awesome-wm

I have been looking for a way to start some custom apps when I login to my session in LightDM. So far, I have found two different ways:

**1. Customise .xinitrc:** For example, if I want to add a terminal window whenever I start the X server, I would only have to add `xterm -geometry 80x50+494+51 &` before `exec awesome`.

**2. Add some apps to rc.lua:** as seen [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/startup-applications-awesomewm/), the applications would start when AwesomeWM starts.

The methods are clear, but I have found a problem which made me think of what option would be better.

The first way would only work if I explicitly type `startx` in a TTY. Starting the X server without that command (for example, turning on the computer normally) will not start the applications. So how could I prevent this from happening?

The main question here, though, is: in case I can make `.xinitrc` work, would it be a 'better' (in terms of efficiency and specially security) way to proceed than editing my own copy of `rc.lua`?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2018:**

Using the XDG autostart is still the standard compliant way to do this. However Awesome v4.3 adds a new [awful.spawn.once](https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.spawn.html#once) function which takes care of saving the application "single instance" property directly in the X server. This allows the `spawn` to be called multiple time while being executed only once. It works across restart.

**Original:**

The best is to implement the XDG autostart protocol. It is usually about adding files to `~/.config/autostart` then having a script or a daemon take care of starting the apps. This script or daemon is then either started by the session manager or from `.xinitrc`.

`rc.lua` should not be used for Autostart as it can be restarted at random time (`mod4+ctrl+r`) and re-execute everything. Some users have elaborate systems to detect if something has already been launched, but in my opinion it's not worth it.

The second best way is directly from `.xinitrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that AwesomeWM autorun programs are better when done well

Why = If you exit one of your autorun *always" programs and want to restart them you  (a) restart X [closing everything in the process], (b) relaunch them from a shell [output messages now go to that shell], (c) create special re-launch code in rc.lua [on top of the launch code you put in .xinitrc

How = This works well for me...
a) As soon after the debug lines in rc.lua add...

```
    local gears         = { table   = require( "gears.table" )          ,
                            p_call  = require( "gears.protected_call" ) }

    gears.p_call( dofile, path_this .. "runonce.lua" )
```

b) And here's the "when done well" part (IMHO) that is in runonce.lua...

```
    local naughty   = require( "naughty" )
    local awful     = { spawn = require( "awful.spawn" ) }
    local string    = { sub = string.sub        ,
                        find = string.find      ,
                        format = string.format  }

    -- This function makes sure the application is not restarted when awesome is reloaded
    local function run_once( command )
        local args_start = string.find( command, " " )
        local pgrep_name = args_start and command:sub( 0, args_start - 1 ) or command

        local command = "pgrep -u $USER -x " .. pgrep_name .. " > /dev/null || (" .. command .. ")"

        awful.spawn.easy_async_with_shell(
            command,
            function( stdout, stderr, exitreason, exitcode )
                if exitcode ~= 0 then
                    naughty.notify({
                        preset  = naughty.config.presets.critical           ,
                        text    = string.format(    "%s\n\n%s\n%s\n%s\n%s", 
                                                    command,
                                                    stdout,
                                                    stderr,
                                                    exitreason,
                                                    exitcode )              })
                end
            end )
    end

    -- Start these if not already running
    run_once( "guake &> /dev/null" )
    run_once( "remmina -i &> /dev/null" )
    run_once( "skypeforlinux" )
```

Why I believe it is done well...

1) Works with programs that have parameters [only searches for the name, not the args]
2) Has an alert if things go wrong [without killing Awesome]
3) Only edit the bottom section

Finally...
mod+ctrl+r reloads awesome [nothing really changes, just resets memmory] and of course the apps you always want are re-launched exactly the same way they were the first time

Comment: Note that AwesomeWM git-master (to be v4.3) has a more accurate version built-in https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.spawn.html#once

Comment: Nice to know a standard method will be coming - I'll check it out when I update to the pending 4.3 release

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple script named `/usr/local/bin/awesome_run_once`:

```
#!/bin/bash

pgrep $@ > /dev/null || ($@ &)
```

At the end of my `~/.config/awesome/rc.lua`, I add some calls to it with the app I want to run:

```
-- auto start programs
awful.util.spawn("awesome_run_once wicd-client")
awful.util.spawn("awesome_run_once redshift")
awful.util.spawn("awesome_run_once nextcloud")
```

Works fine enough.

I got this idea from [Autostart - awesome](https://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Autostart) but the page doesn't seem to be online anymore...